# Does quantum mechanics somehow generalize the concept of affine tensor?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, tensor-calculus, linear-algebra

From https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AffineTensor.html

and
https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Affine_tensor

It seems affine tensor transforms via orthogonal matrices:
$$A^{T} A = 1  $$

But, in quantum mechanics, the transformations of operator and basis are unitary:
$$U^{\dagger} U = 1 $$

My question is, does quantum mechanics adopt a general/modified version of an affine tensor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, an affine tensor is usually just called a tensor. The qualifier 'affine' here is to distinguish this from a tensor field which is a field of tensors and which is also usually called a tensor, particularly in GR. To define an (affine) tensor, we use the tensor product. For example:

> $V^3 := V \otimes V \otimes V$

The quantum mechanics of composite systems uses tensors, however, the tensor product here is usually on *different* vector spaces. So for example:

> $U \otimes V$

Thus it is not the same as an (affine) tensor. However, if it is a composite of one or more identical systems, then this of course reduces to the concept of an (affine) tensor.

So, yes. The concept of tensor space does generalise that of an (affine) tensor - with a proviso - dual spaces aren't used.

Comment: I would add that the question seems to be implicitly considering real vector spaces (as the transformations are orthogonal) whilst in QM the vector spaces are typically complex (and so use unitary transformations)

Comment: It seems I stuck at more basis level. Does the concept tensor, in the most general form, have to require orthogonality in the transformation matrix (I think affine is a special type)? Consider the contraction between (1,0) and (0,1) tensors, $ A^{\mu}  B_{\nu} (e_{\mu}, e^{\nu}) = A^{\mu}  B_{\nu} \delta_{\mu}^{\nu} =  A^{\mu}  B_{\mu} $, if I picked up another basis such that $ A'^{\mu}  B'_{\nu} (e'_{\mu}, e'^{\nu}) $, does the contraction between new basis has to be  $(e'_{\mu}, e'^{\nu}) = \delta_{\mu}^{\nu}$? Orthogonality looks nicer, but does it has to be in the most general form?

Comment: @AlphaF20: Tensors like vectors don't require indices. Its only in a basis that they acquire them. Then changing from one basis to another gives the transformation tensor. It doesn't require orthogonality because this would require an inner product but in general, a tensor can be defined without invoking this extra structure.

Comment: @Alpha20: Unfortunately, this intrinsic definition of a tensor is not often made clear in physical texts and often, not even in mathematical ones. There are three ways to define a tensor: transformationally, algebraically and geometrically. These are all equivalent.

Comment: I have one more question. About the Christoffel symbol. Typically to show the Christoffel symbol is not a tensor, is to look at its transformation with indices. Is there any abstract approach to do so (without using indices)? Thanks.